# Select does not work - Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

i'm beginning in Oracle. I use SQL Developer and i'm trying to Launch an SQL request like that :

```
select date_depart,* from train where no_train='111';
```

An error message is displayed : "missing expression"
How i can resolve this problem please ?

Comment: Why do you want to show the `tran_no` twice? That column will be included by `*`. It's generlly bad practice to use `*` though, it's better to list all the columns you actually want.

Comment: `select no_train,train.* from train where no_train='111';`

Comment: it's just an issue of readability! even when i write another column instead of no_engin, it does not work

Comment: The part I don't understand - if you are looking for train information for `no_train = 111`, you already know the `no_train` value, it will be `111`. Why do you even need that column in the result - let alone *twice*? (To be clear, this is a question about the business requirement in the first place, never mind the code.)

Comment: @mathguy i'm just trying to display "a column + all column" why ? because when i have many columns in my table and i want to show a column that is exist in the end for exemple, so that's why i'm trying like that. (mybe in my question it was well that i made another column instead of `no_train`)

Comment: Understood... You have the answer in the Answers - and in a Comment as well. Note Alex's observation about datatype, too.

Comment: @AlexPoole i'm just trying to display "a column + all column" why ? because when i have many columns in my table and i want to show a column that is exist in the end for exemple, so that's why i'm trying like that. I had the answer in the answers and comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you want a result containing the column `no_train` followed by all the columns of the table, including `no_train` that will be showed twice, you may need to add an alias:

```
select no_train, t.*
from train t
where no_train='111';
```

For example, with a table like this

```
create table train(no_train, descr) as ( select 111, 'descr' from dual);
```

this will give:

```
SQL> select no_train, t.*
  2  from train t
  3  where no_train='111';

  NO_TRAIN   NO_TRAIN DESCR
---------- ---------- -----
       111        111 descr
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use any other column or expression alongside the `*` wildcard, you have to specify which table the `*` refers too, either using the full name:

```
select no_train, train.* from train where no_train='111';
```

or with an alias:

```
select t.no_train, t.* from train t where no_train='111';
```

But as the wildcard `*` gets all columns, you'll see `train_no` twice. It's better to list the columns you want:

```
select t.train_no, t.train_type, t.depot, ... -- whatever your real columns are
from train t
where t.train_no = 111
```

If the train number is actually a number data type you should not be enclosing the literal `111` in quotes. Always use the right data type, don't force or rely on implicit data conversion.